Game Unity Programming
I'm making an arrow that points to an enemy position based on the player's position and rotation but the code that I have doesn't work very well.
Vector3 FirstPoint = (Player.position - transform.position).normalized; // Direção inicial do objeto
        Vector3 LastPoint = (Inimigo.position - transform.position).normalized; // Direção final do objeto

        float angle = Vector3.Angle(FirstPoint, LastPoint);

        Quaternion PlayerRotation = Player.rotation;
        float KartYrotation = Player.eulerAngles.y;
        if (KartYrotation > 180f)
        {
            KartYrotation -= 360f;
        }
        Quaternion rightrotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 0f, angle - KartYrotation);

        transform.rotation = rightrotation;  

I expect the arrow to point to the enemy.

you could save yourself a lot of error and set the arrow up soi it points forwards and just tell it to "look at" the enemy

@goncalo asadelta if my answer helped, be sure to mark it as accepted.

There are many ways to do this, but here's a fairly easy one:

Create an empty game object (called "Arrow" in the image below) in the editor and make the representation of your arrow a child of that. In my example, I'm using a Cylinder as the representation.

In the editor, orient your arrow representation so that if the enemy were standing right in front of the arrow, it would be pointed the right way:




Add a script to your player object that makes the arrow a child of the player, then updates its orientation to look at the enemy:

public class PointArrowAtEnemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject arrow;
    public Transform enemy;

    void Start()
    {
        // First, set the arrow as our child
        arrow.transform.SetParent(transform);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Center the arrow relative to our position
        arrow.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;

        // Have the arrow look at the enemy position
        arrow.transform.LookAt(enemy);
    }
}

There are other ways you could do this too, depending on your game setup.
